# Injector service is undefined in callback

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject the `Injector` service in a custom callback so the callback can use it to instanciate it's own dependencies. Like so :

```
labelObservable: (injector: Injector) => {
    let myCustomService = injector.get<CustomService>(CustomService);
    return myCustomService.getSomethingFromTheAPI();
}
```

However, the `injector` service is undefined in my callback, but isn't when i'm calling this callback

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public injector: Injector) {

} 

ngOnInit() {
    ROUTES.filter(value => value.labelObservable).map(value => {
          (value.labelObservable.call(this.injector)).subscribe(observableValue => {
                /* doing something with the observable value */
            })
        });
    /* Irrelvent init code */
}
```

This is irritating because it was working when I was injecting a service with a `HTTPClient` property and doing the request "manually".

Is there something I missed, maybe I'm in a digest cycle and I need to wait,I have no idea.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing something, and it is not related to the Injector service itself. 
The `call` function takes two parameters, however, I was sending only one. 
Therefore, the `args` parameters was empty. This caused the callback parameter to be undefined.